# font is not importing on sass

Tags: html, sass

I'm trying to import a google font using @font-face on sass but it's not working and I can't figure out why, can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```css
@font-face{
font-family: 'Space Grotesk';
src: url(fonts.google.com/specimen/Space+Grotesk);
font-weight: 500;
} 

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
body{
font-family: 'Space Grotesk';
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card-background">
    <div class="card-front-image">
  <h3>0000 0000 0000 0000</h3>
  <h4>Jane Appleseed</h4>
  <h4>00/00</h4>
</div>
<div class="card-back-image">
  000
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you forgot the `https://` at  the beginning of the font's URL

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the URL and should then set the font as a variable that can be used later IE:

```
@import url(http://fonts.google.com/specimen/Space+Grotesk);

// Variable
$space-grotesk: 'Space Grotesk', serif;  

body {
    font-family: $space-grotesk;
}
```

This is the reasoning for using SASS -- Making it easier to use variables that are only set one time IE

```
@import url(http://fonts.google.com/specimen/Space+Grotesk);
@import url(http://fonts.google.com/specimen/Some+Font);
@import url(http://fonts.google.com/specimen/Foo+Bar);

// Variable
$space-grotesk: 'Space Grotesk', serif;  
$button-font: 'Other Font', sans-serif;  
$list-font: 'Foo Bar', serif;  

body {
    font-family: $space-grotesk;
}

button {
    font-family: $button-font;
}

li {
    font-family: $list-font;
}
```

Comment: thank you @zak I tried this but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Be sure you are using the correct font type `serif` vs `sans-serif` vs `sans` etc etc  Furthermore your import looks incomplete ..  You should be specifying parameters IE `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Space+Grotesk|Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700`

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the styles you want and import them

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Grotesk:wght@400;600&display=swap');
```

Usage

```
font-family: 'Space Grotesk', sans-serif;
```

Or in variables

```
$base-font: 'Space Grotesk', sans-serif

// use anywhere
body {
   font-family: $base-font;
}
```

Comment: How is this any more information than I gave in my answer?

Comment: Because you didn't specify all the features needed when importing. Best regards.

Comment: They are called parameters, and yes, I did in the comment.

Comment: Yes you are right about parameters :) and 'parameters' in your comment are not suitable for importing.